# Column ordering in GI screens

Tags: acumatica

In the GI screen, in results grid tab i have arranged some columns in order like a,b,c but the output is showing as a,c,b, if I do Restore Column Configuration then I could able to see them in arranged order in results grid like a,b,c. My question is, I have multiple users, so for some users still it is showing as a,c,b only. How can I set same order for all users?

Comment: I don't know that it is possible (reset for all users). Maybe someone has a good answer. This question i think has been asked before but for non GI page as its the same issue. Maybe save it as a new GI if its really important.

Comment: Hello Brendan, thanks for the input, I have made changes to the default Acumatica GI screens, I just made the fields inactive for which I don't want, so if default GI has a,b,c in order then I made b as inactive and added my new field after c and moved up just above c. As b is in middle in inactive mode, maybe this is causing the issue? Not sure just guess.

Comment: It shouldn't matter and I have seen this on non GI pages.

Comment: oh.., will let you know if we found the solution.

Comment: Hello Brendan, I got the solution from here @ https://www.timrodman.com/augforums/acumatica-generic-inquiries/column-ordering-in-gi-screens/ 
After looking into the solution, I have realized that I used this earlier :)

Comment: Perfect. Be sure to answer your own question to close out the this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer @ https://www.timrodman.com/augforums/acumatica-generic-inquiries/column-ordering-in-gi-screens/

Not sure, but the configuration may reset if any package is published.